# How to configure the correct connection of objects with armature?

Tags: mesh, objects, armature, bones

I have an armature to which I would like to attach objects moving with the bones, instead of those that were before. When I try to attach them using Ctrl+P, nothing happens, or the objects rotate and distort (when using the Armature Deform - With Automatic weights)

What do I need to do so that the objects move and rotate correctly according to the armature?

Thank in advance for the answer.

[image: example]

Comment: You need to apply all transforms on the objects, parent with armature deform->empty groups, and then manually weight paint all of the objects.

Comment: The bones are point to the wrong direction. They are perpendicular because the armature not really compatible with Blender. In this case the autoweight tool won't work. When you import the model from fbx (may be some other formats) there are options to rotate the bones but it will ruin the animations if you already have.

Comment: @Nathan Can you tell me a little more? I still know very little about the program.

Comment: @FFeller In another model with exactly the same armature, I attached objects in the same way and everything worked. I can't understand why it doesn't work with this.

Comment: @CrazyFox I can tell you to follow along with a few rigging tutorials.  Just google "Blender rigging tutorial" and pick a couple.

Comment: @Nathan The tutorials are all in English, and I've already watched a few. There was no similar problem anywhere.